# SQL Statement Using Embedded Selects

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Okay, this works:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(USER), COUNT(DISTINCT (USER)) AS numrows 
FROM `sometable` 
GROUP BY USER 
ORDER BY USER asc 
LIMIT 0, 20
```

What I need to do now is to limit results to numrows > X. Tried a number of solutions using embedded selects, but no luck.

Comment: Excuse me. But IMHO your question is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT(USER),
    COUNT(DISTINCT (USER)) AS numrows
FROM
    `sometable`
GROUP BY
    USER
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT (USER)) > 10
ORDER BY
    USER asc
LIMIT 0, 20
```

`HAVING` is like `WHERE`, but is applied to already grouped data. You can use it to filter out some groups that not met your requirements.

Comment: Yep, that did the trick. Cheers. Forgot about HAVING. Thanks!

Comment: One issue I just noticed. numrows value no longer correct - only correct if > 0. Gives same value regardless of value in HAVING section. Value is that of my original SQL query that does not use HAVING.

Answer (score 1):

You can omit `DISTINCT` keyword because you are already grouping it. And to filter out the result from aggregated column, use `HAVING`:

```
SELECT  USER, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT USER) AS numrows 
FROM    sometable 
GROUP   BY USER 
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT USER) > ???  -- << define the value here
ORDER   BY USER asc 
LIMIT   0, 20
```

`HAVING` and `WHERE` are filtering keywords but the difference them is that `HAVING` supports the use of aggregate function that will be filtered while `WHERE` cannot.